# Copy certain positions from a double array to another double array

Tags: c#, arrays

So, I have one array Double[] inputx, which have 100 elements.

What I want to do is to copy into another array, let say Double[] inputxx, but only the elements situated on the positions that respect the condition: i%5 == 0 .

Comment: Programming language? Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Linq:

```
Double[] inputxx = inputx.Where((x, i) => i % 5 == 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Samich! And if I want now just to MessageBox.Show("inputxx: " + inputxx[i] ) in a loop for ... the count variable goes from 1 to ...?

Comment: It's just an array, so you can get the Length of the array and loop to this value. In case if you will call ToList() you need to call Count property of the List object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general: If your array indices start from 0, you can safely initialize `i` with `0`, as `0 % 5 == 0`. Then, add 5 until you reach the end of the array.

C# code might look like:

```
Double[] inputxx = new Double[inputx.Length / 5];
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < inputx.Length; i += 5)
{
     inputxx[x] = inputx[i];
     x++;
}
```